# Finding the volume of a pyramid (the vector way)

Tags: linear-algebra, cross-product, vectors

#### The problem

I have 4 points

$
P \; (-1,2,0) \\
Q \; (2,1,3) \\
R \; (1,0,1) \\
S \; (3,-2,3)
$

and I want to find the volume of a pyramid. What I'm most concerned here is the appropriate strategy to go about this.

#### What I've tried

1. Since the volume is calculated by $\mbox{base} \cdot \mbox{height} \times \frac{1}{3}$ I first find the base
2. The base in this case $\frac{1}{2}\lVert PQ\times QR \rVert$
3. Next the height vector will co collinear with the normal vector, so I find that from the cross product ${\bf n} = PQ\times QR$

By this point, I've decided that $S$ is the top of the pyramid, and $PQR$ is the base. What I struggle with is finding the distance between the top and base, I.e. the height.

In my mind, that has to be a scaled version of the $\bf n$, but how do I find the scale? Or is my approach broken?

Comment: The norm of $\textbf{n}$ is $\|PQ \times QR \|$, which gives you the scale. To deduce the formula of the volume note that $\rm{height}= |\langle \frac{\bf{n}}{\|\bf{n}\|},QS \rangle|$ and$\langle QP \times QR, QS \rangle = \det(QP,QR,QS)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** The volume of a [Parallelepiped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelepiped) is given by the determinant of three of its spanning vectors. (That is $Q-P$, $R-P$ and $S-P$, for instance)

Comment: So in this I only have to adjust the volume to $\frac{1}{3}$?

Comment: Yes, or you can calculate the distance of the point S from the plane going through the points P,Q and R with the coordinate-form n1 x1 + n2 x2 + n3 x3 = d of the plane.

Comment: It'll result in $V =\frac16 \det(A)$

Comment: Why the $\frac{1}{6}$?

Comment: The 1/2 comes from the triangle PQR

Comment: It all makes sense now, it's as if I've seen the light. This is profound. I'm going to chase this feeling from now on.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
'Move' $S$ to the origin of coordinates. We get the points $\vec{p} = \pars{-2,4,-3}$, $\vec{q} = \pars{-1,3,0}$, $\vec{r} = \pars{-2,2,-2}$ and $\vec{s} = \pars{0,0,0}$ which correspond to the "old" points $P$, $Q$, $R$ y $S$, respectively. With the 'new' points:
$$
V = \int_{V}\dd V = \int_{V}{\nabla\cdot\vec{r} \over 3}\,\dd V
= {1 \over 3}\int_{S}\vec{r}\cdot\dd\vec{S}\tag{1}
$$
where we used Gauss's theorem. The integration over the 'walls' vanishes out since $\vec{r}\cdot\dd\vec{S} = 0$. There remains an integration over a triangle
$\pars{~\mbox{the pyramid base}\ B~}$which vertexes at $\vec{p}$, $\vec{q}$ and $\vec{r}$.

$\pars{1}$ is reduced to
$\ds{V = {1 \over 3}\int_{B}\vec{r}\cdot\hat{n}\,\dd S}$ where $\hat{n}$ is a perpendicular unit vector to $B$. $\pars{~\dd S \equiv \verts{\dd\vec{S}}~}$:

$$
\hat{n}
\equiv
{\pars{\vec{p} - \vec{q}} \times \pars{\vec{p} - \vec{r}}
 \over
 \verts{\pars{\vec{p} - \vec{q}} \times \pars{\vec{p} - \vec{r}}}}\,,\quad
\left\vert%
\begin{array}{rcl}
\pars{\vec{p} - \vec{q}} \times \pars{\vec{p} - \vec{r}}
& = &
\pars{-1,1,-3}\times\pars{0,2,-1}
\\
& = & \pars{5,-1,-2}
\\[2mm]
\verts{\pars{\vec{p} - \vec{q}} \times \pars{\vec{p} - \vec{r}}}
& = &
\root{30}
\\[2mm]
\hat{n} & = & {1 \over \root{30}}\,\pars{5,-1,-2}
\end{array}\right.
$$
Then,
$$
V = {\root{30} \over 90}\int_{B}\pars{5x - y -2z}\dd S
$$
Can you take from here ?

Comment: Most certainly not, yet. This does seem very beautiful, even though it's a bit like using a nuclear reactor to power a mill. Thanks for the inspiration!